# Geometric introduction to exterior algebra

Tags: reference-request, exterior-algebra

Could anyone point me to a geometric introduction to exterior algebra (meaning, one with a good number of figures and/or verbal descriptions of geometric objects in it)? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[On the Visualisation of Differential Forms](https://web.archive.org/w/20050210114926/http://homepage.mac.com/sigfpe/Mathematics/forms.pdf)

[A Geometric Approach to Differential Forms](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.GT/0306194)

[Teaching Electromagnetic Field Theory Using Differential Forms](http://contentdm.lib.byu.edu/cdm/ref/collection/IR/id/722)

Comment: On the Visualisation of Differential Forms. The requested resource (/w/20050210114926/http://homepage.mac.com/sigfpe/Mathematics/forms.pdf) is not available.

Comment: Try with archive.org.

Comment: the published version: A Geometric Approach to Differential Forms http://ishare.iask.sina.com.cn/download/explain.php?fileid=19887653 click 下载

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/828035/Mathematics/forms.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Mathematical physicists see much of their work as an generalization of exterior algebra, so try:

- [The geometry of physics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107602602) by Theodore Frenkel.

A lot of this stuff was invented before good computer graphics, but Wikipedia has some neat figures as well:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at chapter 4 in Gravitation by Misner, Thorne and Wheeler. It describes differential forms and various operations on them in terms of the honeycomb constructions described by john in his answer taking electromagnetism as the main example.